# What is causing Excel 2010 to consume over 3GB of memory during a custom sort operation?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

When I run a custom sort operation in Excel 2010, the operation consumes over 3GB of memory and takes several minutes to complete on one computer. However, on another computer with the exact same hardware, the sort operation takes less than a second and consumes an insignificant amount of memory.

**Hardware**

- HP 280 G1 MT

**Software**

- OS: Windows 7 Pro (64-bit)
- Office 2010: Excel 2010 (64-bit)

**Sort Operation**

The sheet has just over 17,000 rows and 20 columns. The cells in the first column are formatted as *Date*. The sheet contains a mixture of cell types formatted as either *Date* or *General*.

1. Click the Select All button
2. GoTo the "Data" menu
3. Check "My data has headers"
4. Choose the first column
5. Sort On "Values"
6. Sort order "Oldest to Newest"

**Things I've already tried to narrow down the cause of the problem.**

- Reimaged the computer. *It was not a corrupt user profile.*
- Performed a clean Windows boot. *There was no third party software conflicting with Excel 2010.*
- Ran Office repair. *The Excel 2010 installation was not corrupt.*
- Ran Excel as Administrator. *The issue was not related to NTFS file permissions.*
- Ran Excel in Safe Mode. *The issue was not caused by an Excel add-in or plugin.*
- I set the ForceFullCalculation property of the Workbook to true.
- I turned off multi-threaded processing under Advanced options.
- Ran HP Hardware Diagnostics. All quick tests passed. *The issue was probably not related to a hardware failure.*
- I replaced step 1 in the sort procedure above. Instead of selecting all cells, I selected only the cells with data in them using the shortcut Shift + Control + End. I was able to complete the sort quickly just like on the good computer. *The issue is related to running a sort after using the Select All button to select all of the cells in the sheet.*

What is causing Excel 2010 to consume so much memory and take so long to complete the sort operation?

Comment: Do they have identical CPUs?

Comment: Yes. I can reproduce the issue on one computer, but the issue does not occur on another computer that is the exact same model with the same processor.